# Rest Client - how get JSONObject as a response?

Tags: android, json, gson, resttemplate, android-annotations

I'm following this guide - https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API and I am trying skip JSON<->POJO conversion and work on pure `JSONObject` (or gson's `JsonObject`). What should I write as an server's answer?

```
@Rest("url")
public interface JsonRest
{
    @Get("/getjson")
    JSONObject getTime();
        // or... ? 
    @Get("/getjson")
    ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getTime();
        // or... ? 
    @Get("/getjson")
    JsonObject getTime();  
}
```

In all cases I am getting `"{}"` as a response, but it's contains correct data after POJO conversion. Which `HTTPMessageConverter` should I provide? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add GsonHttpMessageConverter to RestTemplate and try this:

```
@Get("/getjson")
JsonElement getSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported by Spring Android RestTemplate by default. You should probably provide your own provider.

You could look at how `GsonHttpMessageConverter` is implemented [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@org.springframework.android%24spring-android-rest-template@1.0.0.RELEASE@org%24springframework%24http%24converter%24json%24GsonHttpMessageConverter.java) and then implement your own solution based on that.

Comment: Actually it worked when I set response to... JsonElement. I completely don't get it. Btw. what's the best way for providing custom headers to @Rest interface? Do I need to override any method?

Comment: Another issue - when I want to send payload as a JSON object I can put as a parameter... JsonObject. So response has to be JsonElement, but parameter might be JsonObject... ?

Comment: Pierre-Yves Ricau, the link you provided is not there